# How to use Postgres autoincrement with psycopg, getting exception thrown when using DEFAULT

Tags: python, postgresql, primary-key, psycopg2

Using Python / **psycopg**, what SQL statement will work to use the auto increment feature for a **primary key / id field**?

When I use **DEFAULT** as the placeholder, I get:

```
Exception in Class ==> LoadDatasource column "DEFAULT" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO SOURCE VALUES ("DEFAULT","value", "value", ...)
```

I am attempting to use "blind inserts" by not specifying the column names like so:

```
INSERT into <table_name> values();
```

The reason I am using "blind inserts".  I have generated a CSV that matches the order of the database columns, and simply want to insert the CSV (but I need to do this programatically, as I am cleaning, manipulating some of the data along the way), but the values are in order.

The only value missing in the CSV is the primary key / id column, which I am trying to use 'DEFAULT' so that it lets Postgres figure that out.

The table was created with:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists sources
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT` should not be quoted. It’s a keyword in Postgres.

The other suggestion is to not use blind inserts, so that you can define the columns that the CSV file covers, omitting the auto increment column, so that you don’t need to use “default” and Postgres will automatically figure out what to do with the column for you